# UITableView not showing all cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to use a UITableView, but as you can see in the image below, when the view is loaded, part of it is cut of by the UINavigationBar. When I follow one of the selections through to another view, and go back to the view picture below, it fixes itself. Has anyone ever encountered this before?

[image]

Comment: How are you declaring the frame of the tableview? IB or through code?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ? If so, you need to set it to use the layout guides from the view controller when pinning it to super view edges.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your app is running under iOS 7. Since iOS 7 the content of your view controller scrolls under the top bars, here the UINavigationBar and the status bar. But in your case your bars are fully opaque. So to prevent that behaviour you can set

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

in your view controller.

**EDIT:**
I've set up a sample project in Xcode 6 - Beta 6 and configured your setup in IB and didn't make any adjustments in the controller code and it's working from scratch:
[image: Interface Builder]
[image: iOS 8 Simulator]

Are you able to post same relevant code from your project? What happens in viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear if the problem fixes itself when you're leaving the current view?

Comment: Doesn't do anything unfortunately. I'm running iOS 8, Xcode 6.

Comment: Can you write a bit about your architecture, e. g.:

    - Are you using a UITableViewController?
    - Is your UITableView == self.view?

Comment: Yes to both of those. Its attached to a UITabViewController.

Comment: I've edited my post and added some screenshots from a sample project I set up and added further questions.

Answer (score 0):

In storyborad  attribute inspector set scroll indicator : shows Horizontal indicator to NO

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar you used is translucent, you can use the following code to disable the translucent.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```